# check checkbox based on the array value using angular or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
  OriganalArray=[
{member_Key: 1},
{member_Key: 2},
{member_Key: 3},
{member_Key: 4},
{member_Key: 5},
{member_Key: 6},
{member_Key: 7},
{member_Key: 8},
{member_Key: 9},
]
```

I binded the OriganalArray in a table with the checkbox

```
 FilterArray=[
{member_Key: 1},
{member_Key: 2},
{member_Key: 3},
   ]
```

Now the check box has to automaticaly select based on the FilterArray when i click button

Comment: *"I binded the OriganalArray in a table with the checkbox"* - Which checkbox...? How did you do it? using angular..? *"..when i click button"* -What button..? Please don't expect the users to do all your work from the scratch. Share the code require to replicate what you have so far.

Comment: can you brief more ?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do something like this with `.slice()`, for demo i have used radios instead:

```js
var OriganalArray=[
{member_Key: 1},
{member_Key: 2},
{member_Key: 3},
{member_Key: 4},
{member_Key: 5},
{member_Key: 6},
{member_Key: 7},
{member_Key: 8},
{member_Key: 9}
]

$('button').click(function(){
  var filtered = OriganalArray.slice(0, +$(':radio:checked').val());
  $('p').html('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(filtered)+'</pre>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>3 <input name='filter' type='radio' value='3'></label>
<label>4 <input name='filter' type='radio' value='4'></label>
<button>Filter</button>
<p></p>
```